# VS Code fold expressions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17

Basically I have the following code ripped from Stroustrup's book:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... T>
int sum(T... v)
{
    return (0 + ... + v);
}

int main()
{
    int a = sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

It compiles fine on `GCC`, `Clang` and `MSVC` with `/std:c++latest` flag.

The problem is that in VS Code I get the following error:

[image]

Do I have some error here or is it just VS Code? And if so, can I somehow turn on the newest (or I think second to the newest) features in VS Code's linter?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: Windows 10, got VS 2017 and Win10 SDK installed as well

Comment: I'd try setting `C_Cpp.default.cppStandard` to C++17.

Comment: One last hint would be using `clangd` as language server for C++: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd